# Windows 7 Network Filters – VPN KillSwitch is not deactivatable and can not be found

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, internet, internet-filter

I have been using a VPN which comes with a built-in KillSwitch functionality.
For reasons unknown to me this KillSwitch persists after

- closing the VPN
- deactivating the KillSwitch setting
- uninstalling/reinstalling
- etc..

A reset of WinSock / IPv4 + IPv6 does not help either.

The Windows diagnostics tool shows a possible culprit to be a setting with the Filtername "*ZoogKillSwitch*" (Which is also the name of the VPN in question). However I am unable to find such a Setting/Filter anywhere on my system (See image below)

[Internet Connectivity Diagnostics and Network Filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4slA.png)

It also does not show up in the *filters.xml* after a `netsh wfp show filters`

Does anyone have an idea on where one might find this ominious "*ZoogKillSwitch*" Filter?

Addition:
I have found so far that terminating the service `Base Filter Engine` restores connectivity; However this is unacceptable because of the security risks involved in terminating it.

Addition 2:

It also works to rename the following registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SYSTEM / CurrentControlSet / services /  BFE /
> Parameters / Policy / Persistent / Filter

to anything else – this disables ALL filters however. So the question by now would be on how to identify the offending filter setting, since all filters there are just identified similar to this naming scheme:

```
{25fad5f7-8ccb-4c5a-99b8-c374fc597504}
```

and only contain data in non-human readable format

```
01 10 08 00 cc cc cc cc b8 02 00 00 00 00 ......
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have an answer to this particular problem. It is not a satisfying one, but it works for this particular instance. After Trial+Error I have determinded the responsible filters in the registry; Upon deletion of those, connectivity is restored to the system.

The values I had to delete were:

### in key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\BFE\Parameters\Policy\Persistent\Filter

### Values:

```
{05db5e1c-a3d0-4865-9429-09742af3de49}

{27438efa-2154-47ef-b1a2-f1980fdc1d47}
{27283f00-eb09-4686-978b-d7c27bc56ec4}

{4a3bf223-6c8e-43b0-83c5-1512c146a1c3}

{5223540f-a693-4d4a-8e63-e8b9794c55dd}

{570fc36a-8e01-42e0-9d80-6621a701fc2e}
{583e51ac-cef7-4cde-8bab-1400d746eb3c}

{61a3835c-4f38-41aa-9241-ac8b09757c4f}

{731e5d35-1e56-4467-8c0a-8afbd4e4f546}
{758772b6-be42-440c-a9e1-d757a2003f60}
{77935b38-16e1-47a0-a8c2-a1b481fc05c4}
{7a1684f0-db48-4404-a291-534a7745d34b}
{7ab1b049-81d6-4010-bd7d-f67782453abe}

{8169be5c-ca48-4f0e-85fa-19d68aa0938c}
{8ac27b95-c70f-493d-a7d6-9f77a676fa43}

{b352e0bd-74fa-4de3-9131-59a515a820ae}
{b47ebc03-51bf-41fe-bf58-e0c2bd2641c8}
{b5402d45-52f4-4639-8d73-975c1e5033a2}
{b553d1f5-e0a1-4975-af79-eeed58a54113}
{b58b3d59-9403-4fb1-bb76-91e0ea70d212}

{e3b9e5c5-44e4-4047-9ca7-f2003022038c}
{eb8fc9e2-9a02-4817-b5ff-3ae27e885aec}
```